# Meals and products - flexible design

Tags: sql, database-design

I'm trying to learn SQL and Entity Framework, to do so I want to create an application helping with managing the meals, but I have a problem to make a flexible desgin for my entities. I've thought about storing information about products and their nutritional properties per 100 grams in a table called Products. The thing is that users should be able to choose the product (from the Products table) and then set a quantity of eaten one and add it to their meal. In a result, user should see in a meal plan products with nutritional properties properly multiplied by given quantity.

Example:

**1. Given Products' record**: {*ProductID*: 1, *Name*: "Chicken", *Quantity*: 100, *Kilocalorie*: 99, *Protein*: 20, *Carbohydrate*: 0, *Fat*: 1.3}

**2.User:** ate 250 grams of chicken.

**3.Output:** {MealID: 1,

ProductID: 1, *Quantity*: 250, *Kilocalorie*: 247.5, *Protein*: 50, *Carbohydrate*: 0, *Fat*: 3.25,

other Products...}

I don't know if I should create another table storing those products with user's defined quantity or should I calculate it somehow based on this quantity and Products' record. I know that we shouldn't store duplicates, so idea of having another table seems bad. I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the nutritional values are directly related to the product, I would separate the nutritional information into its own table, with each nutritional value as its own record (not column).

```
Product:
ProductID
ProductDescription

Nutrition:
NutritionID
NutritionDescription

NutritionValues:
ProductID
NutrionID
ValuePer100Grams
```

This allows you to add new nutritional values for a product without changing the schema, as it would just be adding another record to the Nutrition and NutritionValues tables, and also does not require that every product have a value input for every nutritional attribute.

I would also recommend a ServingSize table that determines the multiplier for a product to convert a serving size to 100 grams.

```
ServingSize:
ProductID
GramsPerServing
```

This would allow the flexibility to have your user enter the quantity of food (one slice of bread) and you handle the conversion to grams for them.

Comment: So, the example of yuor design would look like this: Product{ProductID:1, ProductDescription: "Chicken"},  Nutrition {NutritionID: 1, NutritionDescription: Protein} NutritionValues{ProductID: 1, NutritionID: 1, ValuePer100Grams: 20}?

Comment: @Donios Yes.  That would make it easy to add new nutrients and also does not require a value for every possible nutrient.  If you don't know how much zinc Chicken has, you don't have to input it.  Alternatively, if you know that Broccoli has 0 grams Saturated Fat, you can either input it with 0 as the value, or you could not input Saturated Fat for that entry.  It is up to you.

Comment: To capture the meal, you would combine the User ID with the Product ID and the grams eaten into a Meal table.  Your nutritional value consumed would be (ValuePer100Grams/100.0 * GramsEaten) Grouped By Nutrient, Product, User

Comment: Okay, I see it now, you have explained it really clearly. Thank you very much!